# Undefined local variables in Rails 3 partials after upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9.3, partials

I know there are several posts on this issue but none of the solutions I've read help here.

I've just upgraded from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3p429 and now, I get undefined local variable in my partials.

I am calling a partial (from a partial in case that's relevant) thusly:

```
= render :partial => 'user_name', :locals => {:user => item_user, :extra_class => "active"}
```

In the partial, I access these locals thusly:

```
- if(current_user and user.silhouette_user_id.to_i == current_user.silhouette_user_id)
    = notranslate(current_user.full_name)
- else
    - if !local_assigns[:extra_class].nil?
        = notranslate(link_to( h(user.full_name), stream_url(:user_id => user.silhouette_user_id), :class => extra_class )) rescue "Anonymous"
    - else 
        = notranslate(link_to( h(user.full_name), stream_url(:user_id => user.silhouette_user_id) )) rescue "Anonymous"
    = notranslate(link_to "Pro", "#", :class => "badge badge-pro", :title => "#{user.part_name} is pro") if SSO.is_pro? user
```

I can access the locals via the local_assigns hash, so if I add these lines to the top, I have access:

- user = local_assigns[:user]
- extra_class = local_assigns[:extra_class]

I could live with that.  However, it gets worse.  user is an ActiveRecord model object.  I cannot, however, access the attributes of this object with user.attribute notation.  Instead I have to user user[:attribute].

I could *still* get by with this except that some of the attributes of user are actually methods, which I cannot access using user[:method].

I thought it might be the Rails, which was at 3.1.12 so I upgraded to 3.2.13 with no change.

Any ideas?  Could it be the HAML processor?  All other posts that were solved used ERB.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way for rendering partials (it's correct way for Rails 3):

```
= render 'user_name', user: item_user, extra_class: "active"
```

And access to objects using `user` and `extra_class`

Comment: Noone else having this issue?

Comment: I solved this issue.  It was caused by my custom define_new_methods on the user. c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941607/devise-current-user-weird-behavior-after-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9-3/17985434#17985434