# Devise current_user weird behavior after upgrade to ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-1.9.3

I have upgraded by project from ree-1.8.7 to 1.9.2p429.

I have an attribute in my devise model named silhouette_user_id.  In views and occasionally in my ruby code, calling

```
current_user.silhouette_user_id
```

returns a different (and WRONG) value than

```
current_user[:silhouette_user_id]
```

which returns the right value.

Though I *could* search and replace to fix this, I'm worried that other attributes will behave the same way.  This is a LARGE project and I really need to determine why this is happening.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean "WRONG". It's out of the blue id, some other id or what? There's no magic so there must be a reason for that.

Comment: Yes, it returns a different id.  Not totally random.  An id of a different user object (e.g. @user) from the same session.  Which id varies depending on the page displayed.  For instance a view of users that displays silhouette_user_id=100 (for example) as the last user in the view results in the current_user.silhouette_user_id retrieving the 100!   I guess if we focused on the difference between how an ActiveRecord model attribute is retrieved when using . notation vs. hash [] notation, it might get me somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "different user object (e.g. @user) from the same session"?

Comment: user instance variable (e.g. @user) that was instantiated for a different user record within the session.  For example, listing users the current_user is following.

Comment: I still don't think that it might be anyhow connected with upgrade, but it will be very hard to debug without reading through code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.  During the upgrade I had tried to update how I was defining new methods for the User class.  Unfortunately, I did it wrong.  I used

```
  def define_new_method(key, value)
    self.class.send(:define_method, key.to_sym) do
       value
    end
  end
```

which actually changed the methods for the CLASS User rather than the instance for which it was intended.  Changing to this:

```
  def define_new_method(key, value)
    define_singleton_method key.to_sym, lambda { value }
  end
```

resulted in the new methods being defined only for the instance intended and not for the current_user instance.